# populating custom Listview with parse database

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform

I'm developing an Android App with a Listview populated with a database in Parse.

I can connect my list view with parse and by this side everything is working. The problem is that I want to show one image and three text in the row of the Listview but the app only shows the image and one text. I can't show the image 150x100dp only a small image is showed.

I don't know how to show all data in the row.

This is my code.

> MainActivity
>
> public class MainActivity extends Activity {
>
> ```
> private ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> mainAdapter;
> private CustomAdapter urgentTodosAdapter;
> private ListView listView;
>
>
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_listado_musica;
>
>
>     // Initialize main ParseQueryAdapter
>     mainAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this, "Musica");
>     mainAdapter.setTextKey("titulo");
>     mainAdapter.setTextKey("artista");
>     mainAdapter.setTextKey("album");
>     mainAdapter.setImageKey("imagen");
>
>     // Initialize the subclass of ParseQueryAdapter
>     urgentTodosAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this);
>
>     // Initialize ListView and set initial view to mainAdapter
>     listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
>     listView.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
>     mainAdapter.loadObjects();
>
>
> }
> ```
>
> }
>
> custom_list.xml
>
> ```
> <com.parse.ParseImageView
>     android:id="@+id/imagen"
>     android:layout_width="150dp"
>     android:layout_height="100dp"
>     android:background="@drawable/no_picture"
>     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>
>     />
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/titulo"
>     android:layout_width="80dp"
>     android:layout_height="21dp"
>     android:textColor="#FF0000"
>     android:text="titulo"
>     android:textIsSelectable="true"
>     android:clickable="true"
>     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imagen"
>     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
>
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/artista"
>     android:layout_width="80dp"
>     android:layout_height="21dp"
>     android:text="artista"
>     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imagen"
>     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/titulo"
>     android:layout_alignStart="@+id/titulo" />
>
> <TextView
>     android:layout_width="80dp"
>     android:layout_height="21dp"
>     android:text="album"
>     android:id="@+id/album"
>     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imagen"
>     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/artista"
>     android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/artista"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
>     android:layout_marginStart="29dp" />
> ```
>
> CustomAdapter.java
>
> public class CustomAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter {
>
> ```
> public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
>     // Use the QueryFactory to construct a PQA that will only show
>     // Todos marked as high-pri
>     super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
>         public ParseQuery create() {
>             ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Musica");
>             //query.whereEqualTo("high pry", "true");
>             return query;
>         }
>     });
> }
>
> // Customize the layout by overriding getItemView
> @Override
> public View getItemView(ParseObject object, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
>     if (v == null) {
>         v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.custom_list, null);
>     }
>
>     super.getItemView(object, v, parent);
>
>     // Add and download the image
>     ParseImageView todoImage = (ParseImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imagen);
>     ParseFile imageFile = object.getParseFile("imagen");
>     if (imageFile != null) {
>         todoImage.setParseFile(imageFile);
>         todoImage.loadInBackground();
>     }
>
>     // Add the title view
>     TextView titleTextView1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
>     titleTextView1.setText(object.getString("titulo"));
>
>     // Add a reminder of how long this item has been outstanding
>     TextView titleTextView2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.localidad);
>     titleTextView2.setText(object.getString("artista"));
>
>     TextView titleTextView3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.consola);
>     titleTextView3.setText(object.getString("album"));
>
>
>     return v;
> }
> ```
>
> }
>
> activity_listado_musica.xml
>
> ```
> <ListView
>     android:id="@+id/list"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
> ```

Someone can help me? I think I'm doing something wrong in the adapter but I don't know what.

There are missed parts of code in the xml files because it's not showed by the editor I don't know why. Sorry

thanks in advance
regards,

Comment: check this example app [MealSpotting](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/MealSpotting)

Comment: thanks, I'll check, I was following another example from the same programer,

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code is the only call you are making to parse. and in this case `ParseQueryAdapter` only calls one `setTextKey` and one `setImageKey` for it's own adapter:

```
mainAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this, "Musica");
mainAdapter.setTextKey("titulo");
mainAdapter.setTextKey("artista");
mainAdapter.setTextKey("album");
mainAdapter.setImageKey("imagen");
```

So, because you are using a custom list item, you remove this part and let the `@Override` of `getItemView` do the heavy lifting.